# Problems with rule-based mapping in Azure Dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have multiple XMLs in an Azure Blob. I want to extract certain datapoints and sort them into an Azure SQL db.
For this I use Data Flow. The name of certain elements changes sometimes `[random name]` so i would like to set up a rule-based mapping, that fetches the right values every time .

I want to retrieve `IMPORTANT INFORMATION`, which is always located in the first randomly named child of category_a.

Apart from the randomly named object the rest of the structure always stays the same.

This is about the structure:

```
<title>
<category_a>

    <random_name_1>
        <object_a>
            <subobject_object_a>
                <p>IMPORTANT INFORMATION</p>
            </subobject_object_a>
        </object_a>
    </random_name_1>

    <random_name_2>
        <object_a>
            <subobject_object_a>
                <p>IRRELEVANT INFORMATION</p>
            </subobject_object_a>
        </object_a>
    </random_name_2>

</category_a>

<category_b></category_b>
```

How do I need to write the rule based mapping so that I always fetch this value no matter the random name in the middle of the path?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Provide the actual XML's sample data instead of structure. What do you mean by "I would like to make an XML Query like: `.//section_b/*[1]/object_a/here_is_the_cookie/p` "

Comment: Sadly the XML is too big to post it here.
If I can sen it to you in another way please let me know.

Comment: You can just create a sample example for what you are trying to do. Just a sample input and expected output would be enough

Comment: Basically I just want to get the 'very important value' at [p].

Comment: What are all the sections that you have mentioned in the question?

Comment: I tried to update the question is it now clearer? I am sorry to not be able to communicate the problem clearly thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There might be no option to find or use rule-based mapping to retrieve the important information. As a work around, I have used lookup and string manipulation activities to get the result. The following is the pipeline JSON:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "XmlSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "XmlReadSettings",
                            "validationMode": "none",
                            "namespaces": true
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Xml1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "tp",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@replace(replace(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].title.category_a),':')[0],'\"',''),'{','')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable2",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "tp2",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@replace(replace(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].title.category_a[variables('tp')]),':')[0],'\"',''),'{','')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable3",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable2",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "tp3",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@replace(replace(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].title.category_a[variables('tp')][variables('tp2')]),':')[0],'\"',''),'{','')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable4",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable3",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "tp4",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@replace(replace(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].title.category_a[variables('tp')][variables('tp2')][variables('tp3')]),':')[0],'\"',''),'{','')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable5",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable4",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "final",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].title.category_a[variables('tp')][variables('tp2')][variables('tp3')][variables('tp4')]",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "tp": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "tp2": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "tp3": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "tp4": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "final": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

- The lookup has the source xml file. Since we know the `category_a` is a child element, I have started from there to obtain the child element names (in each set variable activity).
- The following is the output image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check that and let you know.